# Getting timeout exception when requesting to remote actor

Tags: java, akka

I am using below code for requesting and getting response from remote actor.  But sometime Iam getting right response but sometime getting timeout exception. Testing both the actor on the same machine. Don't know what I am doing wrong

```
final Timeout timeout = new Timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
final Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(remoteControllerActor, com, timeout);
final String result = (String) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
```

Below Exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [15 seconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:116)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:116)
at scala.concurrent.Await.result(package.scala)
```

Comment: What is the question? An exception doesn't always mean an error. You should be able to configure timeout, or simply ask again.

Comment: Already I set timeout to 15 seconds so I think there is no need to increase timeout more

Comment: The only thing this Exception is telling you is that processing the message in your `remoteControllerActor` takes more than 15 seconds. Probably you need to check what's going on in there instead of just looking at the result of a Timeout.

Comment: Then 15 seconds have passed and you received no answer, so as @hasumedic says, you need to check what is happening (network, server...).

Comment: On remote actor I am just running a simple linux command for getting disk details. Which in general takes some milliseconds to run. And I am saying that sometime I am getting response but sometime not.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution about it. Actually from remoteControllerActor I was making another async request to another remote actor, and in that remote actor, I was running linux command to get disk details, but was not able to parse output properly. That's why I was getting the timeout exception.